# urdu text is being shown letter by letter in my android emulator

Tags: java, android, xml, android-emulator

I am having difficulty to show a complete word of urdu..my code is showing urdu text letter by letter in my android emulator. kindly guide me how to read Urdu. I have already set the URDU Font.thanks

Comment: Please show the relevant code, such as where you set the font. Also show examples of current and expected behavior.

Comment: this only happens in 2.3 its fine above 2.3 os

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get a font file like "urdu.ttf"
Drop it in your asset folder, inside a "fonts" folder
Get a reference of TextView with something like that :

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myCustomTVFont);
```

Grab you font from the asset folder :

```
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/urdu.ttf");
```

Make your TextView look great :

```
tv.setTypeface(tf);
```